# Any connected diagram is a tree of full propagators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, 1pi-effective-action

In  P. Etingof, *Geometry & QFT,* [MIT 2002 online lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/lecture-notes/); Lemma 3.11 (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7266/abdelmalek-abdesselam).)

He says that any connected diagram is a tree of full propagators and (amputated) 1PI vertices and as  proof he says that i obvious.

For me is obvious that any connected diagram is a tree of bare propagators  and (amputated) 1PI vertices,  i am not seeing why any connected diagram is a tree of full propagators.
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: *For me is obvious that any connected diagram is a tree of bare propagators*: at the classical level yes, otherwise you have loops. A tree is a graph free of loops.

Comment: Are loops not  1PI ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Maybe i expressed myself wrong . What i meant to say is that an connected diagram is a tree of bare propagators  whose vertices are 1PI

Comment: Does your definition of 1PI vertices include two-legs vertices?

Comment: An edge $e$ of a connected graph $Γ$ is said to be a bridge, if the graph $Γ$ without $e$ is disconnected. A connected graph without bridges is called 1-particle irreducible  1PI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92919/discussion-between-amilton-moreira-and-mannyc).